# Stuck at defining the borders for a probability density function

Tags: probability

So I'm given a continuous random variable $X$ with a probability density function: $p(x)= \frac{x+1}{2}$ when $-1 < x< 1$ and the random variable $Y=3X^{2}+1$. I need to find the probability density function for $Y$ however I'm stuck. In order in the statement $y1<y<y2$ to find $y1$ and $y2$ I need to solve the equations: $y1=3*(-1)^2+1$ and $y2 = 3*(1)^{2}+1$, both are being equaled to 4 so I only have one border.

Any ideas?

Comment: $\Pr [Y=y] = \Pr [3X^2 +1 =y]= \Pr[X= \pm \frac{y-1}{3}] = \Pr [X= \frac{y-1}{3}] + \Pr[X= - \frac{y-1}{3}]$. Where $y \in [1,4]$

Comment: @mm8511 All your probabilities are $0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Not really, but i did forget a square root

Comment: @mm8511 OP is talking about random variables with densities and you are thinking of them as discrete vaiables.

Answer (score 1):

Since $|X|\le 1$ a.s., we have $Y=3X^2+1\in [ 3\cdot 0^2+1,\ 3\cdot 1 ^2+1]=[1,4]$ a.s. . Now let $y$ be a value in $[1,4)$ and let $\epsilon>0$ be so that $[y,y+\epsilon]$ is included in $[1,4]$. Then:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Bbb P(Y\in[y,y+\epsilon])
&=
\Bbb P(y\le Y\le y+\epsilon)
\\
&=
\Bbb P(y\le 3X^2+1\le y+\epsilon)
\\
&=
\Bbb P(y-1\le 3X^2\le y-1+\epsilon)
\\
&=
\Bbb P\left(\frac 13(y-1)\le X^2\le \frac 13(y-1+\epsilon)\right)
\\[2mm]
&=
\Bbb P\left(-\sqrt{\frac 13(y-1)}\ge X\ge -\sqrt{\frac 13(y-1+\epsilon)}\right)
\\
&+
\Bbb P\left(+\sqrt{\frac 13(y-1)}\le X\le +\sqrt{\frac 13(y-1+\epsilon)}\right)
\\[2mm]
&=
\int
_{-\sqrt{(y-1+\epsilon)/3}}
^{-\sqrt{(y-1)/3}}
\frac 12(x+1)\; dx
\\
&+
\int
^{\sqrt{(y-1+\epsilon)/3}}
_{\sqrt{(y-1)/3}}
\frac 12(x+1)\; dx
\\[2mm]
&=
\left[\ \frac 14(x+1)^2\ \right]
_{-\sqrt{(y-1+\epsilon)/3}}
^{-\sqrt{(y-1)/3}}
+
\left[\ \frac 14(x+1)^2\ \right]
^{\sqrt{(y-1+\epsilon)/3}}
_{\sqrt{(y-1)/3}}
\\[2mm]
\\&\text{and let us denote by $F(x)$ the function $(x+1)^2/4$,}
\\&\text{and by $G(x)$ the function $G(x)=F(x)-F(-x)=\frac 14(x^2+2x+1)-\frac 14(x^2-2x+1)=x$,}
\\[2mm]
&=
F(+\sqrt{(y-1+\epsilon)/3})
-
F(-\sqrt{(y-1+\epsilon)/3})
\\
&\qquad
-F(+\sqrt{(y-1)/3})
+
F(-\sqrt{(y-1)/3})
\\
&=
G(\sqrt{(y-1+\epsilon)/3}
-
G(\sqrt{(y-1)/3}
\\
&=
\sqrt{(y-1+\epsilon)/3}
-
\sqrt{(y-1)/3}
\ .\end{aligned}
$$
And now we can put the hands on the density (which exists, something based on the above computation shows it),
it is a function
$\rho(y)$ with support in $[1,4]$, and for $y$ in this interval it is given by
$$
\rho(y)=
\lim_{\epsilon\searrow 0}\frac 1{\epsilon}
\Bbb P(Y\in[y,y+\epsilon])
=
\frac\partial{\partial \epsilon}
\Big(
\sqrt{(y-1+\epsilon)/3}
\Big)
\Big|_{\epsilon=0}
=\frac 1{2\sqrt{3(y-1)}}
\ .
$$
I always check in such situations...

```
sage: var('y');
sage: integral( 1/2/sqrt((y-1)*3), y, 1, 4)
1
```

Answer (score 0):

$P\{3X^{2}+1\leq y\}=P\{-\sqrt {\frac {y-1} 3} \leq X \leq \sqrt {\frac {y-1} 3}\}=\int_{-\sqrt {\frac {y-1} 3}}^{\sqrt {\frac {y-1} 3}} \frac {1+x} 2\, dx$ provided $1 <y <4$ and the probability is $1$ for $y >4$. I leave it to you to differentiate and get the density function.